# Problems with TagSet

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

I am new with TagSet and TagSetDelayed and I'm not understanding properly how they works. I introduced the following definition:

```
KK /: D[KK @@ Thread[t@Range[8]], t[j_]] := KKd @@ Join[{j}, Thread[t@Range[8]]]
```

The following expression returns the correct result

```
In[]:= D[KK @@ Thread[t@Range[8]], t[3]]
Out[]:= KKd[3, t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]]
```

If now I try something slightly different

```
In[]:=D[Exp[KK @@ Thread[t @ Range[8]]], t[3]] //InputForm

Out[]:=E^KK[t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]]*
Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][KK][t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4],  t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]]
```

Why in the second example the code does not return the expected result (i.e. `Exp[KK[t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]]] KKd[3, t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]]`)?

Also, is there a way to use Range in a general way? I mean define something like

```
KK /: D[KK @@ Thread[t@Range[n_]], t[j_]] := KKd @@ Join[{j}, Thread[t@Range[n]]]
```

Now it returns `"Range specification in Range[n_] does not have appropriate bounds"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) instead (as alluded to by Daniel):

```
KK /: Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][KK] = KKd[3, ##]&;
```

Then:

```
D[Exp[KK @@ Thread[t @ Range[8]]], t[3]]
```

> E^KK[t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]] KKd[3, t[1], t[2], t[3],
> t[4], t[5], t[6], t[7], t[8]]

To define [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for each possible argument, you can do:

```
Table[
    With[{i=i}, KK /: (Derivative @@ UnitVector[8,i])[KK] = KKd[i, ##]&],
    {i, 8}
];
```

Another idea is to use [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition):

```
KK /: Derivative[a__][KK] := With[{i = First @ FirstPosition[{a}, 1]},
    KKd[i, ##]& /; MatchQ[Sort @ Tally[{a}], {{0, _}, {1, 1}}]
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the definition of KK:

```
?? KK
```

[image]

You defined the derivative of KK with specific arguments relative to t[_]

Now consider:

```
 D[Exp[KK @@ Thread[t@Range[8]]], t[3]]
```

[image]

Here we need the derivative of KK relative to the third argument. These arguments are now considered general and not covered by your definition.

You need to define the derivative relative to general arguments to make this work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So this mean that I have to introduce definitions for derivatives with respect to each argument if I want to obtain the correct result for a generic t[_]?

Comment: Yes, However, note, t[_] is not generic. You would need e.g.: t1_ or x1_...